# Unable to find cookie that was set a request ago

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to develop a simple single sign on solution using ashx file for setting/deleting cookies. .Net 4.0, C#.
I am making a web request (from sitea.com/) to an ashx resource (on a different domain siteb.com/file.ashx) to set a cookie, then I make another request (from sitec.com/) to the same resource (at siteb.com/file.ashx) to see if the same cookie exists. Unfortunately, it comes back as null. When I fiddle it, I can see cookie being there (in request/response headers on siteb.com) on both occasions.

What I don't understand is, how can it be not available via code. I tried using context.Request.Cookies (context comes from public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) method), HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies, also on Response, but no success.

```
HttpCookie AuthCookie = context.Request.Cookies["SiteCookie"];
```

PS: I am writing code on all ends, that is making requests and checking cookie validations. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Cookies are bound to clients. From your description (request FROM sitea and then FROM sitec) it sounds like there are two different clients making requests. Are you sure that the cookie is somehow passed between these requests at the client side? Also, if this is not for educational purposes, do not develop your own SSO solutions. There are at least few of them which are mature and ready to be used.

Comment: The site's secure content is not that valuable hence I am looking for a simple sso solution without compromising security. I just added some more info as a comment to Tomas's answer below. Btw, what 3rd part sso solutions would you recommend if I may ask?

Comment: Well, there's WS-Federation and it's almost like 1st party - you have Windows Identity Foundation available which simplifies the development significantly. Please read the free MS ebook: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx, all the details are there.

Comment: Thanks! it sounds like quite verbose solution but it might be too overwhelming for me and requirements.

Comment: Benefits of an enterprise SSO are obvious. It opens unexpected possibilities of integration of you application with others. Suddenly you are open for scenarios you've never thought of. I Souls seriously think of investing you time in learning something new and valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies have domain property, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain.aspx. So it seems that your cookie is set for domain siteb.com, thus unavailable for other domains.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to access siteb.com cookie from siteb.com domain... basically siteb.com acts as a service which will return true/false to its clients based on cookie existence. So first I set the cookie from sitea.com by calling siteb.com/file.ashx?p=setcookie => this will set the cookie on siteb.com and returns true, then I check for the same cookie from sitec.com by calling siteb.com/file.ashx?p=checkcookie =>but comes back false.

Comment: Are you also setting the path property (you can't access cookies for paths that are not its parent): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.path

Comment: No I am not setting the path property.

Comment: @xaoil well, that there may well be your problem - documentation implies that root is the default value, but if omitted, the actual value set is that of the current directory - so you can later access that cookie only from the same directory or its subdirectories (and not from its parents or siblings) - also, if you are ever updating the cookie, be sure to set the path again because it gets reset to the default value - in fact, make it your habit to **always** set the path